# TensorFlow ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run the last part of the code below I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 28 but received input with shape (None, 30, 30)
```

```
import pandas as pd                       
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, GRU, SimpleRNN, LSTM, Bidirectional, Activation, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CNNmodel = keras.Sequential()  
CNNmodel.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu', input_shape=(20,28))) # 32 convolution filters used each of size 2
CNNmodel.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))        # 64 convolution filters used each of size 3
CNNmodel.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(1,)))            # choose the best features via pooling
CNNmodel.add(Dropout(0.25))                           # randomly turn neurons on and off to improve convergence
CNNmodel.add(Flatten())                               # flatten we only want a classification output
CNNmodel.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))            # fully connected to get all relevant data
CNNmodel.add(Dropout(0.1))                            # one more dropout
CNNmodel.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))          # output 

lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=1e-2,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.9)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

CNNmodel.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

CNNhistory = CNNmodel.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),  epochs=20, batch_size=128) # Getting score metrics

scores = CNNmodel.evaluate(x_test, y_test) 
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: can you pleas add example of your input data?

Comment: the data that I use is the data of the names of Indonesian people who have been labeled with their gender

Comment: but how is structured? I mean, if you can add an example row of the data input it would be great

Comment: Specifically, you could share some code for how you read/process the input data, without sharing the data itself. The error is an incompatibility between the input data and the input the model expects, so without the input processing it is very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

**Working sample code**

```
import pandas as pd                       
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, GRU, SimpleRNN, LSTM, Bidirectional, Activation, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

CNNmodel = keras.Sequential()  
CNNmodel.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28))) # 32 convolution filters used each of size 2
CNNmodel.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))        # 64 convolution filters used each of size 3
CNNmodel.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(1,)))            # choose the best features via pooling
CNNmodel.add(Dropout(0.25))                           # randomly turn neurons on and off to improve convergence
CNNmodel.add(Flatten())                               # flatten we only want a classification output
CNNmodel.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))            # fully connected to get all relevant data
CNNmodel.add(Dropout(0.1))                            # one more dropout
CNNmodel.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 

lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=1e-2,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.9)

opt = keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

CNNmodel.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

CNNhistory = CNNmodel.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),  epochs=20, batch_size=128)
```

**Output**

```
Epoch 1/20
469/469 [==============================] - 14s 28ms/step - loss: -3719534848.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -11388519424.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 2/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 18ms/step - loss: -25869672448.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -44974247936.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 3/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: -69248000000.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -99721273344.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 4/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: -133157298176.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -175103967232.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 5/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -216887148544.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -270619656192.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 6/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -320444530688.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -385881538560.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 7/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -443233828864.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -520282669056.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 8/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -584527708160.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -673431617536.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 9/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: -743466008576.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -844648939520.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 10/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 17ms/step - loss: -920933564416.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -1033648603136.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 11/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -1113547472896.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -1239565729792.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 12/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -1324937117696.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -1462383280128.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 13/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -1552220815360.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -1701631885312.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 14/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -1793859387392.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -1956641505280.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 15/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -2052668915712.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -2227197444096.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 16/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 20ms/step - loss: -2327011393536.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -2512955113472.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 17/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -2612614660096.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -2813191520256.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 18/20
469/469 [==============================] - 8s 18ms/step - loss: -2914698395648.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -3127708745728.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 19/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 18ms/step - loss: -3229450240000.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -3455992463360.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 20/20
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 19ms/step - loss: -3558048268288.0000 - accuracy: 0.1124 - val_loss: -3797768994816.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.1135
```